# Angular 6 - Ng-fullcalendar issue

Tags: angular6, fullcalendar

The following is my runtime enviroment:

- *Angular CLI* version `6`.
- *ng-fullcalendar* version `1.6.2`.
- *fullcalendar* vesion `3.6.1`

HTML code:

```html
<div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
  <ng-fullcalendar
    #ucCalendar
    [options]="calendarOptions"
    (select)="select($event.detail)"
    (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)"
    (eventDrop)="updateEvent($event.detail)"
    (eventResize)="updateEvent($event.detail)"
    [(eventsModel)]="events"
    (viewRender)="loadEvents($event.detail)"
  ></ng-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

Component code:

```javascript
this.events = resp.data.items.map(item => ({
      start: moment(item.startTime).toDate(),
      end: moment(item.toTime).toDate(),
      item
}));
```

When I try to load events, it shows this error:

```js
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'footprint' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.js:5773)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:381)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:203)
    at constructor.renderFgSegEls (fullcalendar.js:5768)
    at constructor.renderFgRanges (fullcalendar.js:5668)
    at constructor.render (fullcalendar.js:5652)
    at members.constructor.executeEventRender (fullcalendar.js:6559)
    at constructor.executeEventRender (fullcalendar.js:17772)
    at Object.func (fullcalendar.js:8294)
    at constructor.runTask (fullcalendar.js:2667)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the solution but it is a workaround. I had the same error as yours but I'm running *FullCalendar* `v3.10.1`.

The issue might not be in your code but in the *jQuery* version you are running. FullCalendar broke when I went from *jQuery* `v3.2.1` to `v3.5.1`.

I reverted back to *jQuery* `v3.4.1` and it's working again.

Answer (score 1):

For those that for whatever reason need `jQuery@^3.5.0`, you can use similar method described in the jQuery issue describing [3.5 incompatible with FullCalendar 3](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4664). The code fixing this problem can be found at the top of [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_gol/wof7p5m1/3/):

```js
var rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([a-z][^\/\0>\x20\t\r\n\f]*)[^>]*)\/>/gi;
jQuery.htmlPrefilter = function( html ) {
    return html.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" );
};
```

But please be aware that this functionality was removed from jQuery as a [security fix](https://blog.jquery.com/2020/04/10/jquery-3-5-0-released/) and by using this, you're exposing yourself to that attack vector again.